# model is not refresh inside directive after changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, model

I'a got a template with a directive using objects. That directive modifys an elements in the objects list. I can see the object modification in the template but not inside the directive.

I used angularjs 1.5.8

My template :

```html
<div>
   <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="event in vm.events">
         // some html code about event object
      </li>
   </ul>

   <event-directive data-events="vm.events"/>
</div>
```

The directive template :

```html
<div>
   <div data-ng-repeat="event in events" class="event">
      <a data-ng-click="edit(event)">Edit</a>
      // some detail about event
   </div>
</div>
```

The directive is declared liked that :

```js
function eventDirective(/* dependencies */) {
   return {
      template: eventTemplate,
      scope: {
         events: '='
      }
   }
}
```

If I modified and event in my directive I can see changes in the main template ng-repeat loop but the changes are not "propagated" to the directive.
I'm sure I'm doing someting wrong or forgot something as there's similar code in my project that works as expected.
I search for advises or way to solve my problem.

I try to simplify my code but if it's not clear or there's missing information, just tell me.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Maybe you should add more code, edit function perhaps

Comment: It's difficult to give you code without copy/paste all my code. My edit function call a webservice to update the Event in the backend. The service is accessible through the directive dependencies.

The edit function open the modal, call the webservice et notify user that the event changed. Everything works in the main template but the event modification are not propagated to the directive. If a refresh the browser window, I can of course see changes !

Comment: I think the Rubber duck debugging help me one more time.
The problem was a one time binding in the directive template that prevent some properties of my object to be recalculated.
Thanks for your help Bill.